# Ember CLI with http-mock and pretender, how to manage mock data

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js, mocking

I'm new to Javascript in general, especially EmberJS and Ember CLI. I'm trying to figure out what is the best practice to manage mock data within a Ember CLI based project. I'm on 0.1.14 EmberCLI now.

According to Ember CLI documentation, http-mock is the preferred way of providing mock data for Ember Data models. So I use generated http-mock and added some test data to it.

```
  var testData = [
  ...

  ];

  module.exports = function(app) {
    var express = require('express');
    var todosRouter = express.Router();

    todosRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.send({
        "todos": testData
      });
    });
```

Then I found out that the http-mock does not work during integration, so I added Pretende.

```
  import Ember from 'ember';
  import { test } from 'ember-qunit';
  import Pretender from 'pretender';
  import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';

  var App;
  var server;

  var testData = [
    ...
    ];

  module('An Integration test', {
    setup: function() {
      App = startApp();
      server = new Pretender(function(){
        this.get('/api/todos', function(request){
           return [ 200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                    JSON.stringify({'todos': testData) ];
        });
      });
    },
    teardown: function() {
      ...
    }
  });


  test('3 items loaded at startup', function() {
  ...
  });
```

Both http-mock and integration test work fine, then I tried put the test data in a separate module so that they can be shared. The thing is that the integration test uses ES6 style module import, and http-mock uses CommonJS style module definition, and I don't know how to combine them into the project.

If I construct the data into an ES6 module,

```
var mockData = [
...
];


export default {
  all: mockData
};
```

it works with integration test but http-mock complains about unexpected reserved word "export". If a convert it to a CommonJS style module.export, then I can't see the data in the integration test.

Now the questions:

1. I think if Broccoli 'compile' ES6 module into CommonJS format it should work with http-mock, but I have no idea how to do that. Is this the right direction to go, and how?
2. Do I have to use both http-mock and Pretender in the same project? Can I use one for both development and integration test?

I'm stuck here and comments, suggestions and code samples are really appreciated.

Comment: I solved this by just having the mocks defined in two different files, one for AMD modules and one for the `require` style.  It sucks, but I don't know if you can have both exports in the same file.

Comment: @alexlafroscia we are also using both http-mock and pretender separately. Though, I am thinking of keeping both of them but sharing common data. I agree that it sucks.

Comment: as @alexlafroscia mentions I created https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage for precisely this reason. I encourage you to check it out!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think that [this Ember CLI addon, called `ember-cli-mirage`](https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage) might do what you're looking for.  I haven't used it myself yet, but I have heard good things about it and it seems to take care of the case where you want to use a mock server for development and testing without keeping two sets of fixtures.

Comment: I decided to try it and I will never regret it.. Excellent library, and I think it should come packaged with Ember as the *de facto* server mock